# Did the compiler inline calls of std::frexp?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

The compiler explorer says the program calls `frexp` in a loop.

Does that mean the compiler didn't in-line the code for `frexp`?

The code was compiled with `g++ -Ofast -march=native`

[Code at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3CEigen/Eigen%3E%0Ausing+namespace+Eigen%3B%0Avoid+log2_extract_mantissa(ArrayXXf%26+x)+%7B%0A++++std::int32_t*+int_data+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3Cstd::int32_t*%3E(x.data())%3B%0A++++for(Index+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+x.size()%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++++++std::frexp(x.data()%5Bi%5D,+int_data+%2B+i)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-Ofast+-march%3Dnative',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Test (c++):

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;
void log2_extract_mantissa(ArrayXXf& x) {
    // rip mantissa out of floats and store the result as int in-place.
    std::int32_t* int_data = reinterpret_cast<std::int32_t*>(x.data());
    for(Index i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
        std::frexp(x.data()[i], int_data + i);
    }
}
```

Assembly:

```
...
.L3:
        vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [rax+rbx*4]
        lea     rdi, [r12+rbx*4]
        call    frexpf
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+16]
        inc     rbx
        imul    rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+8]
        cmp     rbx, rax
        jl      .L7
...
```

Comment: The assembly says `call frexpf`. That's a call; it's not inlined.

Comment: Note: `-Ofast` pulls some tricks to improve speed that actually breaks standard compliance and can give incorrect results in  some cases - and the speed gains are usually trivial. Unless you *really* know what you are doing and *know* that the situations where you can get incorrect results do not matter to you, I would *not* use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it didn't.

`call frexpf` is a function call to `frexpf`.